# Window Resize don't fire when I stretch the pop up page vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, window-resize

Is there a way to detect the pop up page stretching vertically?

```
function ResizeContent(content) {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (window.parent.document.getElementById(getCookie("iFrameId"))) {
            var windowId = window.parent.document.getElementById(getCookie("iFrameId")).parentNode;
            windowHeight = windowId.style.height.replace("px", ""); // replacing the 'px' so that it will not return NaN
            var divHeight = windowHeight - 100;
            $("#" + content).height(divHeight);
            $("#" + content).height(divHeight);
        }
    });
}
```

So my problem is its detecting when I stretch it from the bottom corner. But when I stretch it vertically, the function will not trigger.

Comment: yes there are more than one way

Comment: show us your code so far